# Testing Desktop Heap Exhaustion

Tags: windows, com

During a support case, we received an error upon calling CoInitialize:  "Not enough storage is available to process this command" (HRESULT: 80070008).  Support has traced it to desktop heap exhaustion due to some problem outside of our product.  I believe  I have a fix in place to make the system more tolerant to this, but I haven't been able to test it.

I have tried using the Sysinternals testlimit  utility (testlimit -u -i), and although it seems to exhaust the desktop heap (Windows can't create new windows and there are some other errors in the system), I can't seem to reproduce this specific error.  Does anyone have advice on how to *test* this particular issue?  Are there other tools that might be helpful?

(Dheapmon is apparently not available for this OS, but as far as I know, that wouldn't help to recreate the issue, anyway)

Comment: Only two ways I know how to fix this problem: uninstall the piggy app that gobbles too much or configure Windows to give the session a bigger heap.  You can also make it smaller, thus giving you a simple way to test your fix.  Ask at superuser.com if you don't know how to configure that.